# What is the inutition behind the Caratheodory criterion for measurable sets?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure, intuition, outer-measure

Before the [criterion of Caratheodory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion) a set $A$ was defined to be measurable iff the inner and outer measure of it coincide $\lambda_*(A)=\lambda^*(A)$. Caratheodory found a definition for measurable sets which only uses the outer measure: $A$ is measurable iff for each set $B$ we have $\lambda^*(B)=\lambda^*(B\cap A) + \lambda^*(B\cap A^C)$.

> What is the intuition behind the criterion of Caratheodory? Why is the property $\forall B: \lambda^*(B)=\lambda^*(B\cap A) + \lambda^*(B\cap A^C)$ equivalent to $\lambda_*(A)=\lambda^*(A)$?

*Background of my question:* This is a follow up of an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2794345/32951) given by [David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248223/david-c-ullrich) in my question [Why is the inner measure problematic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794210/why-is-the-inner-measure-problematic) With his answer I can provide an answer for my question for $A\subseteq B$ and $B$ being a set higher dimensional interval $[a,b)^n$ (or another set for which we already have define its measure). However I do not find a proof that $\lambda^*(B)=\lambda^*(B\cap A) + \lambda^*(B\cap A^C)$ leads to $\lambda_*(A)=\lambda^*(A)$ for $A\not\subseteq B$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability this post should be hepful

Comment: What is your working definition of Lebesgue inner measure?

Comment: @T_M I want to use the same definition as in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/212a/11.pdf : $m_*(A) = \sup\{ m^*(K) : K\subseteq A, K\text{ compact}\}$