# Inner measure doesn't care whether finite or countable

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2806974/844467), to try understanding why the inner measure defined as the $\mu_*(U)=\sup\{\mu(A):A\subset U\text{ is measurable}\}$ is not really used. I copied the answer here :

> Tao talks about this in his measure theory book, which last time I
> checked was still freely available.
>
> He says roughly that there is an asymmetry here because when measuring
> finite unions of boxes, the measure is subadditive and not
> superadditive. This leads to the fact that the Jordan inner measure $$
> m^{*, J}(U) := \sup \{m(A)\ :\ A \subset U\ \text{is a finite union of
> boxes}\} $$ doesn't care whether or not you put finite or countable in
> the definition (because you are taking a supremum and its
> subadditive). So a natural Lebesgue inner measure where you put
> countable here gives no increase in power/resolution of the measure

Does this mean that $$
m^{*, J}_1(U) := \sup \{m(A)\ :\ A \subset U\ \text{is a finite union of
boxes}\} $$ and $$
m^{*, J}_2(U) := \sup \{m(A)\ :\ A \subset U\ \text{is a countable union of
boxes}\} $$

are the same? I don't understand how to use the subadditivity of the supremum to show this.